# Azure Durable Functions Scaling

Tags: azure-functions, distributed-computing, azure-durable-functions

I have a question around scaling Azure durable functions.

I am writing a simulation engine that performs a number (1000's) of quite computationally intensive tasks (Complex maths) that take a relatively short period of time, 10 seconds each approximatley.

I'm using DurableOrchestration to create a fanout of "Activity" Functions.

At the moment when I run the simulation it will queue up the tasks and run 2 tasks per vm as per my configuration below.

```
{ 
        "durableTask": {
            "maxConcurrentActivityFunctions": 2,
            "maxConcurrentOrchestratorFunctions": 10
          }
     }
```

This currently scales out over about over about 20-30 vm's and takes a while to run, a few minutes for my test. It is increasing the number of VM's slowly I guess by looking at the history table).

What I would really like is for my functions to be on a specified number of vm's, say 200 and run the simulation in seconds.

I am on a consumption plan, is this currently possible or Can it be achieved with another App Plan ?

Just thinking, maybe a good idea would be create some sort of ActivityBatch class with a collection of Activity function calls where you can specify an approximation of how long each task will take and a desired runtime.

This way Azure can calculate how many vm's it needs to propagate the functions to so that it can attempt to meet the users requirement.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to directly interfere into Scale Controller (the component which decides on scaling out and amount of instances). It has internal algorithm to determine the scaling parameters based on current utilization metrics like queue size and CPU load. The algorithm is not public and not configurable.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Will ask for this as a feature request.

Answer (score 2):

As Mikhail says you can't directly control it on Consumption Plan but you can "affect" it by putting as much on the backlog as possible at once rather than drip feeding.

As you lower the maxConcurrentActivityFunctions it will result in it scaling to more instances by the end but there is a trade off in terms of how often it scales up and how much use your activity makes of the CPU.

If they are very CPU intensive then I'd be tempted to try dropping the concurrent count to 1 as multiple on the same node at 100% CPU each will just take twice as long as running 1 per node so you may get more instances and a faster start to end time.

It's definitely worth experimenting and for info it will only allocate new instances 
 every 10s at most, according to the docs, I'm not 100% sure if it only adds 1 instance at a time though as I'm sure I've seen it add more than 1 at a time?

Oh and on an App Service plan you could run 200 instances all the time but unless you expect this to be running 24/7 it probably wouldn't be cost effective.

Comment: Small correction: App Service plans only allow up to 20 instances.

Comment: Ahh true, can you get that increased with a support request? If I was being smart I'd have said I meant 200 function instances (which I obviously didn't!) so I guess you could get 20 multi-core servers and then up the maxConcurrentActivityFunctions accordingly to get near to 200

Comment: If you need more than 20 servers, then you'd need to go with an App Service Environment (ASE), which allows you to scale up to 100. It's very pricey though, so definitely not an option for everyone.